# JavaScript Canvas Problem Understanding Object Movement

Tags: javascript, dom, canvas

There is a little extra code here in this question than what is needed. If you change the height of the canvas to be 100, it works.

> I want to understand what is going on here as to why the alien doesn't
> shift directions and move the other way with bottom function (instead it just stops). Why doesn't it work? I'm not asking to fix the problem. I'm wanting to understand why it doesn't work code wise. Here is my logic as to why it should run. What is the issue here?

At the beginning...

- The drop(); function holds true and runs. The speedX==5 is true as speedX=5. The object is less than the canvas height as it starts at the top. And speedY==5 holds true as speedY=5.
- The bottom(); function does not execute as the object height does not equal the canvas height.

When it reaches the bottom...

- The drop function drop(); fails to work as obj.y<can.height is false as the object equals the canvas height at the bottom.
- The bottom(); function holds true as obj.y==can.height. Notice now that speedY=-5 which is important for the next iteration to allow the object to continue to move the other way. Once the object moves up one pixel the obj.y does not equal the canvas height for execution of the bottom(); function. However, bottom(); holds true because speedY=-5 on the previous iteration. This should result in the bottom(); function to continue to move the object upward where the drop(); function continues to be false as speedY must be 5 for it to execute and it is now set to be negative 5.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.createjs.com/createjs-2013.09.25.combined.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
#gameCanvas {
  background-color: lightyellow;
}
</style>
<div class="canvasHolder1">
  <div id="alien"> ︎</div>

<script>
//score does not have id score here 
</script>
  <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="100" height="150">Not supported</canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var stage = new createjs.Stage("gameCanvas");
  var domElement = new createjs.DOMElement(document.getElementById("alien"));
  var object = new createjs.DOMElement(document.getElementById("alien"));
  can = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
  object.x = can.width/2;
  object.y = 1;
  var speedY=5;
  var speedX=5;
        function startGame() {
            stage.addChild(object);
            createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", handleTick);
              function handleTick(event) {
              drop();
              bottom();
              stage.update();
            }
        }
 function drop(){
  if ( speedX==5 && object.y<can.height  && speedY==5){
      object.x += 0;
      object.y +=3;
      speedY=5;
   }
 }
  function bottom(){
   if (object.y==can.height || speedY==-5 ){
     speedY=-5;
     object.y -=3;
     object.x +=1;
   }
 }
</script>
<body onload="startGame();">
    <div >
  <canvas>This browser or document mode doesn't support canvas object.</canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is it you are asking?

Comment: Why doesn't the alien move back up once it hits the bottom of the canvas?

Comment: I made it back late its been answered below. The reason is because everything is being updated every frame so when it comes to collision detection getting a moving object to exactly equal a boundary is rare.  Your character is moving past the `==` point between frames thus no collision. Use greater and less than as mentioned below.

Comment: @Justin Oh that makes sense! It doesn't hit the boundary exactly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `if (object.y==can.height || speedY==-5 ){`. When speeds and acceleration are involved, `==` almost never happens, you are far safer with checking `>=` (or `<=`):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.createjs.com/createjs-2013.09.25.combined.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
#gameCanvas {
  background-color: lightyellow;
}
</style>
<div class="canvasHolder1">
  <div id="alien"> ︎</div>

<script>
//score does not have id score here 
</script>
  <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="100" height="150">Not supported</canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var stage = new createjs.Stage("gameCanvas");
  var domElement = new createjs.DOMElement(document.getElementById("alien"));
  var object = new createjs.DOMElement(document.getElementById("alien"));
  can = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
  object.x = can.width/2;
  object.y = 1;
  var speedY=5;
  var speedX=5;
        function startGame() {
            stage.addChild(object);
            createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", handleTick);
              function handleTick(event) {
              drop();
              bottom();
              stage.update();
            }
        }
 function drop(){
  if ( speedX==5 && object.y<can.height  && speedY==5){
      object.x += 0;
      object.y +=3;
      speedY=5;
   }
 }
  function bottom(){
   if (object.y>=can.height || speedY==-5 ){  // <----- here
     speedY=-5;
     object.y -=3;
     object.x +=1;
   }
 }
</script>
<body onload="startGame();">
    <div >
  <canvas>This browser or document mode doesn't support canvas object.</canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```